# How do I set the activity of the Android Up-button dynamically?

Tags: android, android-intent, up-button

The following two methods seem like they should do the trick, but I can't get them to work. Does anyone how to get these methods to work, or know of another way?

getSupportParentActivityIntent
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#getSupportParentActivityIntent()

onCreateSupportNavigateUpTaskStack
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#onCreateSupportNavigateUpTaskStack(android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder)

Answer (score 1):

[How to implement getSupportParentActivityIntent() to set the activity dynamically for up-button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22088014/how-to-implement-getsupportparentactivityintent-to-set-the-activity-dynamicall/22089806#22089806)